# Generating QR code for Android with High error correction

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing

I'm currently generating a QR code in my Android app but the customer complained that we need to generate codes with [High error correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code#Error_correction).

The code I'm currently using is the following, but the problem is that I don't know how to actually generate the QR image with the certain error connection:

```
private Bitmap encodeAsBitmap(String contents, BarcodeFormat format, int img_width, int img_height) throws WriterException {
        String contentsToEncode = contents;
        if (contentsToEncode == null) {
            return null;
        }
        Map<EncodeHintType, Object> hints = null;
        String encoding = guessAppropriateEncoding(contentsToEncode);
        if (encoding != null) {
            hints = new EnumMap<EncodeHintType, Object>(EncodeHintType.class);
            hints.put(EncodeHintType.CHARACTER_SET, encoding);
        }
        MultiFormatWriter writer = new MultiFormatWriter();
        BitMatrix result;
        try {
            result = writer.encode(contentsToEncode, format, img_width, img_height, hints);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
            // Unsupported format
            return null;
        }
        int width = result.getWidth();
        int height = result.getHeight();
        int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            int offset = y * width;
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                pixels[offset + x] = result.get(x, y) ? BLACK : WHITE;
            }
        }

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        bitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
        return bitmap;
    }
```

Thanks a lot for the help in advance!

Comment: Um, what is `BarcodeFormat`? That is not in the Android SDK. Are you using a library?

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm using ZXing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added the line `hints.put(EncodeHintType.ERROR_CORRECTION, ErrorCorrectionLevel.H);` to my method in order to generate a High correction level, and taking a look at [this](http://www.qrstuff.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/error_correction_levels1.png), I can see the generated one has a high correction level.

Answer (score 0):

If you need online qrcode generator use Google Chart Api.

```
https://chart.googleapis.com//chart?chs="+ width+"x"+ width+"&cht=qr&chl=yourqrcodetext"
```